What is the enable_events on buttons in pysimpleGUI
I wonder what does the parameter enable_events, do for a button (sg.Button).
Indeed, when there is a button in a code, it is always sending an event in the .read().
You don't need to specify enable_events=True AND even if you specify enable_events=False then button still sends an event.
Furthermore, in the reference of PysimpleGUI it is written that the default value of enable_events is False. Do anyone knows what is this about ?
Thank you

The docstring and the call ref both define the field and say when it is used:
https://docs.pysimplegui.com/en/latest/call_reference/tkinter/elements/button/
It's meant for some special situations.


sg.Button
enable_events
Turns on the element specific events. If this button is a target, should it generate an event when filled in

Example Code
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [
    [sg.Input(key='-IN-'), sg.FileBrowse(target="Submit")],
    [sg.Button("Submit", enable_events=True)],
]
window = sg.Window("Title", layout)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break

    print(event, values)

window.close()

Note: Most of time, we don't need to use this options enable_events=True.

Nice example

The enable_events parameter has no effect on button click events in most cases. Button click events are always captured by default, and the primary purpose of the enable_events parameter is to trigger additional events when some specific state or property of the button changes. Therefore, the default value of False does not affect the basic functionality of the button.
If your application only needs to handle button click events, you can ignore this parameter; If you need to catch more complex event changes, consider setting enable_events=True.

Ok thank you,
but then again, what is a point of having the parameter ?
Your answer says "If you need to catch more complex event changes, consider setting enable_events=True." What would that change ?
